# "Computation timed out" when trying to get the size of an ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine python installation

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to get the size of an ImageCollection but get "computation timed out" while processing the getInfo() request. I'm using the python jupyter installation and I'm unsure how to make a callback as suggested in the [javascript tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server).

The request is as follows:

```
area_of_interest_sen = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterDate('2017-06-01', '2018-06-01').filterBounds(jsonf)\
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
s = area_of_interest_sen.size()
print(s.getInfo())
```

Where jsonf is a geometry from a file.

The error goes like this:

```
EEExceptionTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-215-e097e3c89cef> in <module>()
     58 s = area_of_interest_sen.size()
     59 
---> 60 print(s.getInfo())
     61 
     62 area_of_interest_sen = area_of_interest_sen.median().select(bands)

/src/earthengine-api/python/ee/computedobject.py in getInfo(self)
     93       The object can evaluate to anything.
     94     """
---> 95     return data.getValue({'json': self.serialize()})
     96 
     97   def encode(self, encoder):

/src/earthengine-api/python/ee/data.py in getValue(params)
    253   """
    254   params['json_format'] = 'v2'
--> 255   return send_('/value', params)
    256 
    257 

/src/earthengine-api/python/ee/data.py in send_(path, params, opt_method, opt_raw)
    795       raise ee_exception.EEException('Invalid JSON: %s' % content)
    796     if 'error' in json_content:
--> 797       raise ee_exception.EEException(json_content['error']['message'])
    798     if 'data' not in content:
    799       raise ee_exception.EEException('Malformed response: ' + str(content))

EEException: Computation timed out.
```

PS: other than this, the query works. I get the images and I'm able to process through them.

Comment: how big is the region?

Comment: It's a city in Kenya, you can see here the extent: https://ibb.co/R4T1RNz

Comment: shouldn't be a problem, but without having access to the site I can't be sure

Comment: I am able, however, to get the ee.Number(..) object printed as json. Is there any (other) way to parse this?

Comment: I guess `Computation timed out` means that your request is taking too long to complete, may be because the size is too big. Try doing `s = area_of_interest_sen.limit(100).size()` and `print(s.getInfo())`

Comment: This prints 100.

Comment: A quick solution I am thinking of is to split the date range in two or three and finally add all sizes.. you could even automate this..

Comment: Think this might work! Wish there was an easier way though... Thanks!

Comment: If it works, it could be easy making a function to do it for you.. ;)

Comment: Yes, coding it is easy. I mean I wish there was another way to use getInfo() to get a number...

Comment: Update: After counting every 15 days throughout the year because a larger period would yield too many results... I understood that the json geometry I was using was 'too complex' and earth engine wasn't filtering by it, hence I was getting a total of 2776305 images. No wonder (now) why this was taking some time/space to process!